# net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateTime to ORACLE date

Tags: oracle, datetime, java-8, icalendar, ical4j

I have net.fortuna.ical4j.model.DateList which contains 
net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date objects
The output is: 20170522,20170523,20170525
(UTC time zone)
I have to convert it to ORACLE date in SystemDefault timeZone.
I tried to do this:

```
List<DATE> result = new ArrayList<DATE>
for(Date d : rdates){
result.add(new DATE(new Timestamp(d.getTime()));
}
```

But oracle date is different as expected.From net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Date 20170522,20170523,20170525 I got 20170521,20170522,20170524 ORACLE DATE.
There is shifting. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Ical4j Date objects have an underlying timezone that is not defined as part of the formal specification (an implementation quirk).

By default this timezone will be UTC, however you can change this to system default using the following compatibility hint:

net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.date.floating=true